# Importing ERDAS-processed GTOP030 dem data into ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, erdas-imagine

I have two GTOP030 DEM images. After downloading them, I have imported into ERDAS and mosaiced them. Then I have exported it to .tif file in order to open it in ARCGIS. But when I tried to open it in ARCGIS, "the memory could not be 'read'" error message appeared on the screan and turned off ARCGIS. what's wrong with this.

Do you have any idea for this?

Another thing I ask from you is how to remove No data value from this DEM file because min value of this DEM image is -9999?

Comment: Try importing the data as an .img file (Erdas' Imagine's native format) as ArcGIS 9.3 has better support for it than GeoTiffs in my experience

Answer (score 3):

Your version of ArcGIS may make a difference.

ArcGIS 9.1 is known to have serious memory leak issues, and often fails during load/processing of large data.

You can try to "stitch" the images in ArcGIS instead of ERDAS...

Regarding NoData values, try using the **reclassify tool**, but delete all the classes shown in the dialog except no data. Set the new value for no data to 0, and away you go.
It should retain the previous values of all the cells which had data.